# JQuery to Update a <span> tag when typing in a textarea

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

How do I update a  tag in JQuery by what a user is typing in a textaarea?  Onchange appears to only get fired once and not on each letter.

Comment: Look at `keypress`, `keyup` & `keydown` - all are fired as you type.

Comment: doh yay i forgot about those, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    $('span').html($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you can solve this by using [keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(selector).unbind('keyup').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    // update your tag
}).unbind('blur').bind('blur', function(e) {
    // update your tag
}).unbind('paste').bind('paste', function(e) {
    // update your tag
});
```

Comment: @Na7coldwater: Its valid jquery. Depending on a scenario, you can consider them defensive programming. If you tried to bind an event twice, you can get bitten. You might have come across someone complaining that some code is being executed several times in response to a single action

Comment: I guess I've never come across that problem before. I just wonder what would happen if you tried to add two independent listeners that were doing two different things.